# Splitting input string when it contains countires with multiple words

Tags: java

I get multiple countries as an input that i have to split by space. If the country has multiple word it's declared between "". For example

```
Chad Benin Angola Algeria Finland Romania "Democratic Republic of the Congo" Bolivia Uzbekistan Lesotho "United States of America"
```

At the moment im able to split the countries word by word. So United States of America doesnt stay together as one country.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    // Reading data using readLine
    String str = reader.readLine();
    ArrayList<String> sets = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] newStr = str.split("[\\W]");
    boolean check = false;
    for (String s : newStr) {
        sets.add(s);
    }
    System.out.print(sets);
```

How can i split these countries so that the multiword countires dont get split?

Comment: Use a loop over the characters in the string, and a boolean variable to remember whether you are inside double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching what to split, match country names. You need to catch either letters, or letters and spaces between quotes. Match 1 or more letters - `[a-zA-Z]+`, or(`|`) match letters and spaces between quotes - `"[a-zA-Z\s]+"`.

```
    String input = "Chad Benin Angola Algeria Finland Romania \"Democratic Republic of the Congo\" Bolivia Uzbekistan Lesotho \"United States of America\"";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+|\"[a-zA-Z\\s]+\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
      String result = matcher.group();
      if (result.startsWith("\"")) {
        //quotes are matched, so remove them
        result = result.substring(1, result.length() - 1);
      }
      System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, may be I am not intelligent enough, but I do not see any one-line-of-code solution, but I can think of the following solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = "Chad Benin Angola Algeria Finland Romania \"Democratic Republic of the Congo\" Bolivia Uzbekistan Lesotho \"United States of America\"\n";

        List<String> resultCountriesList = new ArrayList<>();
        int currentIndex = 0;
        boolean processingMultiWordsCountry = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
            Optional<String> substringAsOptional = extractNextSubstring(inputString, currentIndex);
            if (substringAsOptional.isPresent()) {
                String substring = substringAsOptional.get();
                currentIndex += substring.length() + 1;
                if (processingMultiWordsCountry) {
                    resultCountriesList.add(substring);
                } else {
                    resultCountriesList.addAll(Arrays.stream(substring.split(" ")).peek(String::trim).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
                processingMultiWordsCountry = !processingMultiWordsCountry;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(resultCountriesList);
    }

    private static Optional<String> extractNextSubstring(String inputString, int currentIndex) {
        if (inputString.length() > currentIndex + 1) {
            return Optional.of(inputString.substring(currentIndex, inputString.indexOf("\"", currentIndex + 1)));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

The result list of the countries, as strings, resides in `resultCountriesList`. That code just iterates over the string, taking substring of the original string - `inputString` from the previous substring index - `currentIndex` to the next occurrence of `\"` symbol. If the substring is present - we continue processing. Also we segregate countries enclosed by `\"` symbol from countries, that resides outside of `\"` by the boolean flag `processingMultiWordsCountry`.

So, at least for now, I cannot find anything better. Also I do not think that this code is ideal, I think there are a lot of possible improvements, so if you consider any - feel free to add a comment. Hope it helped, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach as in the accepted answer but with a shorter regex and without matching and replacing the double quotes (which is quite an expensive procedure, in my opinion):

```
    String in = "Chad Benin Angola Algeria Finland Romania \"Democratic Republic of the Congo\" Bolivia Uzbekistan Lesotho \"United States of America\"";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"|(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
    ArrayList<String> sets = new ArrayList<>();
    while(m.find()) {
        String multiWordCountry = m.group(1);
        if (multiWordCountry != null) {
            sets.add(multiWordCountry);
        } else {
            sets.add(m.group(2));
        }
    }
    System.out.print(sets);
```

Result:

```
[Chad, Benin, Angola, Algeria, Finland, Romania, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Bolivia, Uzbekistan, Lesotho, United States of America]
```